# DefaultPath property of NEProvider Class in iOS

Tags: ios, networking, vpn

**DefaultPath** property of **NEProvider** class in iOS is used to represent current default network path used for connections created by the provider.

I am using this property to notify if interface changes from Wi-Fi to 3G or vice-versa using the KVO method. I am getting notification whenever there is change in interface but sometimes even though there is no change in interface I am getting the notification.

Do anyone face the same problem? 
I tried to use Reachability class to detect network interface change but it is not working when VPN is connected.

Answer (score 0):

It is already mentioned in Apple DOC-

> NWPath contains the viability status and the properties of the path
>   that a network connection will take on a device.
>
> For example, if the path status is NWPathStatusSatisfied, then a
>   connection attempt will be made.
>
> When attached to a specific connection, a path takes all of the
>   connection parameters into account. **For example, if the route for a
>   connection changes or is removed, the path will reflect that change.**
>   Note that every path is evaluated within the context of the process it
>   is running in, and may be different across processes.

As you have mentioned you are tracking  Wi-Fi to 3G or vice-versa , but there is no type of specific documentation check is the mobile is connected through 3G or WiFI or whatsoever.

This the following NWPathStatus you can track down,so it is quite sure that you are catching a wrong notification.

```
enum {
   NWPathStatusInvalid = 0,
   NWPathStatusSatisfied = 1,
   NWPathStatusUnsatisfied = 2,
   NWPathStatusSatisfiable = 3,
}
```

;

Comment: Thanks Vizlix. I can check whether the mobile is connected through 3G or W-Fi using expensive property of NWPath class. If expensive is true then the connection is made through mobile data else it is connected through Wifi. I do get callbacks with different viablity status and I am catching the one with   "NWPathStatusSatisfied " status. When my application moves from background to foreground I face this issue.